# Is x86-64 machine language big endian?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, endianness, machine-code

```
0x0000000000400507 <main+28>:    74 0c  je     0x400515 <main+42>
0x0000000000400509 <main+30>:    bf 28 06 40 00 mov    $0x400628,%edi

..

0x400507 <main+28>: 0x28bf0c74
```

I think shows the machine code is big-endian. Is my conclusion right?

Answer (score 96, accepted):

No, Intel CPUs are little endian: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness

Comment: Oops,seems I'm reading the endianness in the wrong direction,AGAIN...Is there a trick to avoid this kind of problem?

Comment: @kern: little-endian has the least significant byte first, which is the opposite of written numbers where the least significant digit is last.  so having to reverse 0x400628 (actually 0x00400628) to get 28 06 40 00 means its little endian.

Comment: It helps to understand that because computers print on the screen from left to right starting with the lowest memory address in a string buffer, the lowest memory address will be on the left, and the highest will be on the right.

Comment: ...therefore, little endian is "little end gets printed first", and big endian is "big end gets printed first".  Idk, probably doesn't help...

Comment: Endianness determine which byte ends the encoded representation in memory. In other words, which byte uses the largest memory address. If it's the Least Significant Byte, you get little-endian encoding. If it's the Most Significant Byte, you get big-endian encoding.

Comment: @SRO: it's exactly opposite: little-endian means the least significant byte is put in the lowest memory address. In other words, endianess means which byte starts a number.

Comment: Little-endian should have been called little-startian.

Comment: The trick I personally use to figure out little endian is something called '3Ls' -- (lowest address) - (lsb) - (little endian) ; might sound silly, but hey, works for me! :)

Answer (score 38):

First, you need to know that the smallest data unit that nearly all modern CPUs can manipulate is a byte, which is 8 bits. For numbers, we (human beings) write and read from left to right and we write the most significant digit first, so the most significant digit is on the left.

Little-endian byte order implies two things for the CPU:

1. Suppose that the CPU fetches 4 bytes from the memory, e.g. starting at address `0x00`, and that:

   - address `0x00` holds the byte `11111111`, which is `0xFF`;
   - address `0x01` holds the byte `00111100`, which is `0x3C`;
   - address `0x02` holds the byte `00011000`, which is `0x18`;
   - address `0x03` holds the byte `00000000`, which is `0x00`.

   Then, when the CPU interprets these 4 bytes as an integer, it will interpret them as the integer value `0x00183CFF`. That is, the CPU will consider the byte at the highest address as the Most Significant Byte (MSB). That means, for the CPU, the higher the address is, the more significant the byte on that address is.

```
memory address:           0x00      0x01      0x02      0x03
binary value at address:  11111111  00111100  00011000  00000000
equivalent value in hex:  = 0xFF    = 0x3C    = 0x18    = 0x00
```

2. The same thing applies when the CPU writes an integer value like `0x00183CFF` to the memory. It will put `0xFF` at the lowest address, and `0x00` at the highest address. If you (human being) read bytes intuitively from low addresses to high addresses, you read out `FF 3C 18 00`, which byte-for-byte is in the reverse order to how `0x00183CFF` is written.

For BIG-endianness, the CPU reads and writes MSBs at lower addresses and LSBs at higher addresses.